# How to define pure functions in matrix form?

Tags: pure-function

I want to define pure functions x(#1,#2) and y(#1,#2) like
[image]
But they aren't proper pure functions in the current form. How to modify the code?

Comment: You are missing an ampersand ``&``. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuTAZ.png).

Comment: thanks! In your example, how can one define x(#1,#2) and y(#1,#2) separately rather than x and y as a vector together?

Answer (score 4):

You have to reapply `Function` separately for `x` and `y`, for example:

```
{x, y} = Function @@@ (({{Cos[a], Sin[a]},{-Sin[a], Cos[a]}}) . ({{#1},{#2}}))
```

[image: Example 1]

If you want to have a "column vector" like notation on the left side, you have to properly match the levels, for example:

```
{{x}, {y}} = List@*Function @@@ ({{Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {-Sin[a], Cos[a]}} . {{#1}, {#2}});

{{x}, {y}} = Map[Function, {{Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {-Sin[a], Cos[a]}} . {{#1}, {#2}}, {2}];
```

[image: Example 2]

Comment: many thanks! I'm curious why for column vectors it's so much more work, as simply mimicking the row vector approach will yield an error saying: Lists {X} and Cos[a] #1+Sin[a] #2& are not the same shape.